# mvc razor does not redirect to url after action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to open Edit page of a product but after Index action it does not redirect to that page from list page. Here you can find my codes:

On my List page:

```
    function getProductDetail(id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index","ProductDetail")',
            dataType: "html",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "productId": id }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And on my ProductDetailController:

```
   public ActionResult Index(int productId)
        {

            Product prod = GetProductDetail(productId);

            return View(prod);
        }
```

Comment: why are you even doing the ajax call ? Just do the redirect

Comment: @Shyju, jut like ? window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetProductDetail", "ProductDetail",id.)"; But that time I could not pass the id as parameter.

Comment: yes you can .`window.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetProductDetail", "ProductDetail")?productId='+id`,

Comment: @Shyju, Thanks alot.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Do not use ajax if you want to redirect - its pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, you don't need to use AJAX at all in this situation. If you were planning to dynamically update the DOM, using an asynchronous call to the server, this would make sense. In your case, since you are just redirecting to the page, it would make more sense to use an actionlink and get rid of the AJAX call completely.

```
@HTML.ActionLink("Link Text","Index","ProductDetail",new {productId = "1234"}, null))
```